# React indiana scroll - initial scroll doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, scrollto

I would like to initialize my component to an initial scroll with react-indiana-drag-scroll but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

You will find the code on [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-indiana-drag-scroll-initial-scroll-finddomnode-oqyth).

I would like to initialize the scroll on the red line (current time), but the `scrollTo` function doesn't work in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollTo function didn't work because the component isn't fully constructed when we call the function.
Instead of constructing it in `componentDidMount()`, I did it in `componentWillMount()` and called `scrollTo` in `componentDidMount()`.

See the code : [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-indiana-drag-scroll-initial-scroll-finddomnode-7ewt3)